# Java generics extends Cannot infer arguments

Tags: java

Consider the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Parent {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "this is Parent";
            }
        }

        class Child extends Parent {
        }

        class C<T extends Parent> {
            C(T a) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();
        C<Child> c = new C<>(child); // Ok
        C<Parent> d = new C<>(parent); // Ok
        C<Parent> e = new C<>(child); // Ok
        C<Child> f = new C<>(parent); // Compile error - Cannot infer arguments
        
    }
```

The following statement `class C<T extends Parent>` implies that class C can be generalized with anything that inherits from parent including both Child and Parent.
So, when I generalize it with Child, and try to call constructor with a Parent instance, why won't it work?

Comment: A C<Child>'s constructor takes a Child. Parent is not a Child. All Childs are Parents, not all Parents are Childs.

Comment: If `Child` extends `Parent`, then `Child` must contain additional members.  How would those members be defined in a `Parent` constructor?

Comment: `C<Child> e` means that T is Child for that particular instance.  `parent` is not a Child instance, so it is not a valid argument to the `C(T a)` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Child` is a `Parent` but not every `Parent` is a `Child`.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `f` expects a `C` of the type `Child` which is not compatible with the `parent`...it would have worked if it was on the other way around...but on this case you will need to use:

```
C<Parent> f = new C<>(parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

"cannot infer arguments" simply tells you that the compiler can't find a `T` that makes `C<>` assignable to `C<Child>` and still accepts `parent` as the argument to the constructor.

If it picked `Child` as the value of `T` then it would not accept `parent` as the argument, as it's not assignable.

If it picked `Parent` as the value of `T` then the constructor call would work but the resulting object would not be assignable to `C<Child>` (as it would be a `C<Parent>`).